# How can I calculate Position based on another field of Django model instances?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model that looks like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    clicks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def weight(self) -> float:
        return round((self.clicks * 0.7 + self.views * 0.3), 2)
```

Based on `weight`, I'd like to estimate a `position` field of `Image`. It should give a `position` based on `weight` of all instances of `Image`. The higher the `weight`, the higher the `position` (position 1 - highest weight, position 2 - second highest, etc.)

How can I create a function that would take ALL the `Image` instances I have in the DB and calculate `position` for all of them?

Comment: Is this for ordering a queryset?

Comment: I guess, but with making a change (position calculation) for all the Image instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [window function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) to calculate the position of each Image by using [RowNumber](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#rownumber)

```
from django.db.models import Window, F
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber


images_with_position = Image.objects.annotate(
    weight=F('clicks') * 7 + F('views') * 3
).annotate(
    position=Window(expression=RowNumber(), order_by=F('weight').desc())
)
```

Comment: How can I implement this so the `position` field appears in my `Image` model?